# Business entity that accesses data store to validate itself: an SRP violation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, nhibernate, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

Consider the following business entity class. In order to validate itself, it needs to know something about the state of the database, perhaps to prevent a conflict of some kind. So, it has a dependency on the data access layer in order to retrieve this data.

Is it a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle to have a class that encapsulates state, validates the state, and accesses a data store to do so?

```
class MyBusinessObject
{
    private readonly IDataStore DataStore;

    public MyBusinessObject(IDataStore dataStore)
    {
        this.DataStore = dataStore;
    }

    public virtual int? Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    // ... Other properties...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate()
    {
        var data = this.DataStore.GetDataThatInfluencesValidation();
        return this.ValidateUsing(data);
    }

    // ... ValidateUsing method would be in here somewhere ...
}
```

It's throwing a red flag for me because:

- In the context of an ASP.NET MVC controller's Create method, I might make a new instance and pass it to my View() method with no intention of validating, so why should I be required to pass in an IDataStore?
- I'm using NHibernate (and I'm a noob), and it looks like I have to create an IInterceptor that injects dependencies whenever NH creates entities. Maybe that will be fine, but it feels a little bit wrong to me.

I'm starting to think I should use an anemic/DTO type of object for NHibernate to use, and wrap that inside something else that knows all the business rules AND can access a data store if it depends on one. Now that I've typed up my question and title, StackOverflow has suggested some interesting resources: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2842975/674077) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360275/674077).

My question also looks very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949264/business-rules-where-do-they-go-in-oop), but I thought I'd ask it in a different way that more closely matches my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle to have a class that encapsulates state, validates the state, and accesses a data store to do so?" -- You listed three responsibilities so I'm going to answer yes.

The difficulty with validation is that it depends on context. For example, creating a customer record might require just their name but selling them a product requires payment information and a shipping address.

IN MVC, I do low level (data sizes and nullability) validation using data annotations in view models. More complex validation is done using the [specification pattern](http://devlicio.us/blogs/jeff_perrin/archive/2006/12/13/the-specification-pattern.aspx). The specification pattern is easy to implement and flexible.

Comment: Cool, I hadn't heard of the specification pattern. I also just found [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) today via [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8923129/674077). It seems to be using that pattern internally, with each class in the FluentValidation.Validators namespace representing a specification. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose I was also wondering if it would be valid to say that the class's "single responsibility" is to implement business concerns related to a particular type of business object. On the other hand, I don't want to take SRP too far. For example, I wrote a project not long ago that had a few classes with just a single method each.

Comment: Opinions vary, but my opinion is that a business class's  responsibility is to hold state and encapsulate access to state (e.g. status change and status date change must occur together).